# How do I Gson deserializes an interface to a specific implementation?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

If I try to deserialize `Wrapper` class below, which is intended to hold instance of class `HashMap`, the deserializer replaces class for `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`, which is unwanted.

How do I ensure, the actual type of field is what I want, i.e. `HashMap`?

Here's an MCVE to illustrate what I'm asking about:

```
public class HashMapTry {
    public static class Wrapper {
        public String title = "My Title";
        public Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
        Wrapper wrapper2;

        wrapper.map.put("vertical", "1, 0");
        wrapper.map.put("horizontal", "0, 1");

        GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder()
                .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
                .serializeNulls()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .setVersion(1.0)
                .setDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");

        Gson g = gb.create();

        String json = g.toJson(wrapper);
        System.out.println(json);

        wrapper2 = g.fromJson(json, Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(wrapper2.map.getClass());
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "title": "My Title",
  "map": {
    "horizontal": "0, 1",
    "vertical": "1, 0"
  }
}
class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it as a `HashMap` in the Wrapper class. Gson doesn't like deserializing to interfaces *by default* because it has to figure out which class to deserialize to. If it was some random interface (e.g. `interface MyInterface`), it would actually cause a problem because there's no default behavior for that interface, you'd have to specify it, which you can do by registering a [`TypeAdapter`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html).

However, that's too complicated for this situation. Just call it a `HashMap` in your wrapper class. *Only program to interfaces if the implementation doesn't matter, but program to the implementation if it **does matter***, as is clearly the case here.

```
public static class Wrapper {
  public String title = "My Title";

  public HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "title": "My Title",
  "map": {
    "horizontal": "0, 1",
    "vertical": "1, 0"
  }
}
class java.util.HashMap
```